# Google Glass Enterprise Edition 2 set voice command language

Tags: android, google-glass

I try to change the language for voice commands on the Google Glass Enterprise Edition 2. I implemented the functionality as described here: https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/guides/inputs-sensors#voice-commands. How to change the recognition language is not described (and maybe not possible?) So i tried to simply swap the recognition strings to german words, but had no success. Changing the Android system language to german does not work either.

Maybe there is a native Android approach to change the voice recognition language to german (or any other language)?

Just for curiosity I created an instance of the TextToSpeech engine and let the glass speak some words in german, which worked. So I guess the Android OS in general is capable of speaking and listening to german, but somehow the (google glass specific) app initialization/configuration just considers english?
I would be happy, if someone has an idea or a hint on how to change the command recognition to another language.

Answer (score 0):

I am also stuck with this but for voice recognition. I had tried setting EXTRA_LANGUAGE on the new intent but to no avail and changed LOCALE to Japanese. But upon checking release note OPM1.200313.001 it is stated that they added API for voice input(for english language).[OPM1.200313.001 release notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW7qe.png)

With regards to the text to speech it is also stated in the latest release that they added several languages to handle text to speech.

Comment: Sorry interrupting to your issue. I am about to buy a google glass for my company can I know about these points.
How to update our installed APK for new version? Because i saw glass website saying it doesn't include google Play services .also can we send data from google glass to Apple or android device?

Comment: Hi, currently we are just providing our client with the apk so they can manually install the latest apk on their side. But we are planning on creating a script that would just fetch the latest apk from a file storage and install it on the glass connected to the PC running the script. Im not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it. As for the sending of data, I think this could be achieved using tech like websockets, pubsub, etc?